# At what exact time was the Pale Blue Dot image taken?

Tags: voyager, pale-blue-dot

The date of the "Pale Blue Dot" photo is 14 February 1990, but is its exact time of capture (or at least hour) known?

[image]

I was a school child back then, and I am trying to figure out what I was most likely doing at the time the pale blue dot image was taken.

Comment: JPL's catalog entry for [PIA00452](https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA00452) and the related [PIA00450](https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA00450) as well as this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_Blue_Dot#Photograph) subsection; "Three of the frames received showed the Earth as a tiny point of light in empty space. Each frame had been taken using a different color filter: blue, green and violet, with exposure times of 0.72, 0.48 and 0.72 seconds respectively. The three frames were then recombined to produce the image that became Pale Blue Dot."

Comment: It will take some detective work to deduce the time of the particular three frames used to generate the color image. Carl Sagan's book [Pale Blue Dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_Blue_Dot_(book)) just might have the answer also.

Comment: I've pursued this trail as far as reviewing the datasets online at JPL, but I haven't been able to find the actual raw image data in a collection yet. Based on their categorization, I think it's possible this Family Portrait series is in a different dataset, perhaps one of the unsorted ones at the bottom. I'm still unclear if the file times in the archives are relevant to capture time, or merely some processing/archiving date. https://pds-imaging.jpl.nasa.gov/volumes/voyager.html

Comment: Other answers related to this image [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/3758/12102) and [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20132/12102).

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, the raw data used to make the Pale Blue Dot image have not been preserved in NASA's Planetary Data System, which is why other commenters can't find it online. You might try contacting someone at the PDS Rings Node to see if anybody there has the data and metadata.

Comment: I looked through PDS as well. Glad to know someone more familiar then I am with PDS couldn't find it either;-)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to stop by and contribute! If you choose to join as a registered member in the future, you can [easily merge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/303080) memberships to combine reputation points. In the mean time, the "planetary" question [Why would Mars' sky appear blue at dawn and dusk, but red during the middle of the day (reverse of Earth)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/303080) still needs an answer as well :-)

Answer (score 9):

> On Feb. 13, 1990, Voyager 1 warmed up its cameras for three hours.
>   Then the spacecraft’s science platform was pointed at Neptune and the
>   observations began.
>
> After Neptune, it took images of Uranus, Saturn, Mars, the Sun, and
>   then Jupiter, Earth and Venus. The Earth images were taken at 04:48
>   GMT on Feb. 14, 1990, just 34 minutes before Voyager 1 powered off its
>   cameras forever.
>
> It took until May 1, 1990 — and four separate communications passes
>   with NASA's Deep Space Network — for all the image data to finally
>   arrive back on Earth. Voyager 1 had captured images of six of the
>   seven planets targeted as well as the Sun

https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/536/voyager-1s-pale-blue-dot/

Here is that latest reprocessed version of image
https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?release=2020-030

Comment: Just came in to ammend my previous answer with the newly published time, you beat me to it!

Answer (score 6):

It's insane we are nearing this picture's 30 years anniversary! I was trying to find this exact information a couple of years ago, and it's a shame that so little is known about this iconic image, and the raw data are nowhere to be found. The closest I could get to a time taken was from various news articles from back then that I tracked online, reporting on the scheduled photographs to be taken ([JPL news article](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=5705), [UPI article](https://www.upi.com/Archives/1990/02/13/Voyager-1-probe-to-photograph-solar-system/6055634885200/), [New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/1990/02/13/science/voyager-to-snap-first-family-portrait-of-planets-tonight.html)). Assuming the articles are accurate, about 64 photos were to be taken starting at around 1990-02-14 01:00 UTC and for a duration of 4 hours (in actuality they were 60 total if [the caption for the original PIA00452 image](https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA00452) is to be believed, but this caption has other inaccuracies, see below). The UPI article has a more exact-looking time reported, so going with that, the pale blue dot photo was taken somewhere around 1990-02-14 01:12 UTC and 05:12 UTC. Interesting fact: Although the caption in the PIA00452 image says that "Earth was a crescent only 0.12 pixel in size", according to my Celestia simulation, earth should appear as slightly gibbous, with a phase angle @ approx. 82.5 deg., not crescent from the position of Voyager 1 during that time (see attached rendered image).
[image: Celestia rendered image of earth as seen from Voyager 1 at 1990-02-14 01:46 UTC]