# Why does New Horizons have ~2 kg of unusable "trapped" hydrazine?

Tags: new-horizons, monopropellant, mission-anomaly, hydrazine

The 2018 arXiv preprint [The New Horizons Kuiper Belt Extended Mission](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.08393) by the New Horizons team says in section 6, pp. 21-22:

> Nevertheless, throughout the 2020s, there is significant potential for valuable planetary science (and even astrophysics), with New Horizons. Models indicate some 7-10 kg of usable hydrazine **(not including the estimated trapped, ~2 kg)** will remain at the end of the first extended mission to facilitate unique observations.

**Question:** Why does New Horizons have ~2 kg of unusable "trapped" hydrazine? Where is it trapped?

Comment: related: [What's next for New Horizons?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41307/12102) and also [Could New Horizons take a “Pale Blue Dot”-like image this year?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41409/12102) and in Astronomy SE: [Distance to Proxima Centauri (Gaia VS New Horizons parallax program)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34994/7982)

Comment: May be a bladder in the hydrazine tank could not be emptied fully. A bladder is used to separate liquid hydrazine from pressurizing gas in zero gravity. Pipes from the tanks to the thrusters may contain trapped hydrazine too.

Comment: I don't know details about that spacecraft, but it's usually impossible to blow all the propellant out of the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Horizons#Propulsion_and_attitude_control):

The hydrazine tank of New Horizon has an elastomeric diaphragm separating the liquid from the pressurizing gas helium within zero gravity. There are 16 thrusters with redundant plumbing to the tank.

The diaphragm prevents helium entering the plumbing, so all hydrazine within the tubes is trapped. If the elastic diaphragm does not fully align to the "lower half of the tank" some hydrazine may be trapped within the tank too.